# I want to get some data from different sheet of the same file python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to get some data of a single file but from different sheet i tried the code below but it give only the data of the first sheet

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

work = load_workbook(filename=r'the name of the file.xlsx',data_only=True)

for sheet in work.sheetnames[1:len(work.sheetnames)]:
    n = 3
    sheet1 = work[work.sheetnames[n]]
    for val in sheet1.iter_rows(min_row=9, max_row=14, min_col=6, max_col=8, values_only=True):
        print(str(sheet) + " " + str(val))
    n += 1
```

Comment: Do you understand what is going on in your code? Because I don't. Print Sheet but values come from Sheet1. Why are you starting from n = 3? Could you provide us the sheet structure please.

Comment: You are accessing `work.sheetnames[n]` where `n` is ***always*** `3`... Why all that going around? Why not just `work[sheet]`?

Comment: Also please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: `for sheet in work:…`

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have an .xlsx file with 5 sheets named `sheet0, sheet1, sheet2 ..., sheet5`

`work.sheetnames` gives you a list of all sheets `['sheet0', 'sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', ..., 'sheet5']`

When you use:

```
for sheet in work.sheetnames[1:len(work.sheetnames)]:
```

means you are going to do your job from `sheet1` to `sheet5`

After then you have:

```
    n = 3
    sheet1 = work[work.sheetnames[n]]
```

`work.sheetnames[3]` returns the string `'sheet3'`, so variable `sheet1` is always `work['sheet3']` in every iteration. I think this is why your result does not act the way you wish.

The code below probably can fix the problem.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
work = load_workbook(filename=r'the name of the file.xlsx',data_only=True)

for sheet in work.sheetnames[1:len(work.sheetnames)]:
    sheet1 = work[sheet]
    for val in sheet1.iter_rows(min_row=9, max_row=14, min_col=6, max_col=8, values_only=True):
        print(str(sheet) + " " + str(val))
```